# How to tally in stock and salable quantity in magento 2 every time

Tags: magento2

How to manage Magento2 stock and salable quantity field in equally.

Answer (score 0):

In magento2 stock and salable quantity are diffent think.

1. Magento2 stock is the physical quantity which you have.
2. Salable qtuantity is run time calculate. it is cal culate from two data. One is magento stock and another one is reservation table. When customer place order reservation table row are created with that number of item qtuantity. Then this will be minus and then will show in salable qruantiy.

The process is

1. Now for one product salable qty and stock qty is same. sale_qty = 10 || qty = 10
2. Customer place order with 2 qty of this item. sale_qty = 8 || qty = 10
3. After shipment the stock qty will remove. sale_qty = 8 || qty = 8
4. If above order is not shipped it was canceled. sale_qty = 10 || qty = 10

This is is the feature of salable qty and Magento2 stock qty.

Comment: Sir can i manage my product stock and salable quantity are same at every time??

Comment: No, you can not manage salable quantity. Becuse it is not save in databsse. It is real time data.